# I get a result from postman but the seme reqeust doesn't works in c#

Tags: c#, .net, curl, postman

I am trying to scrape a website for a school project
if I do this curl in postman:

```
--header 'authority: dbh.smartschool.be' \
--header 'accept: */*' \
--header 'accept-language: nl-BE,nl-NL;q=0.9,nl;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.6' \
--header 'cache-control: no-cache' \
--header 'content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8' \
--header 'cookie: pid=77573bd5-8567-4bed-8f03-19211db08663; PHPSESSID=s0qf6btgu15su1gesrubrm01lveov6far58r58r2vabvfpo60e' \
--header 'origin: https://dbh.smartschool.be' \
--header 'pragma: no-cache' \
--header 'referer: https://dbh.smartschool.be/' \
--header 'sec-ch-ua: "Chromium";v="106", "Google Chrome";v="106", "Not;A=Brand";v="99"' \
--header 'sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0' \
--header 'sec-ch-ua-platform: "Windows"' \
--header 'sec-fetch-dest: empty' \
--header 'sec-fetch-mode: cors' \
--header 'sec-fetch-site: same-origin' \
--header 'user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/106.0.0.0 Safari/537.36' \
--header 'x-requested-with: XMLHttpRequest' \
--data-raw 'command=%3Crequest%3E%0A%09%3Ccommand%3E%0A%09%09%3Csubsystem%3Eagenda%3C%2Fsubsystem%3E%0A%09%09%3Caction%3Eget%20lessons%3C%2Faction%3E%0A%09%09%3Cparams%3E%0A%09%09%09%3Cparam%20name%3D%22startDateTimestamp%22%3E%3C!%5BCDATA%5B1666611595%5D%5D%3E%3C%2Fparam%3E%0A%09%09%09%3Cparam%20name%3D%22endDateTimestamp%22%3E%3C!%5BCDATA%5B1667043595%5D%5D%3E%3C%2Fparam%3E%0A%09%09%09%3Cparam%20name%3D%22filterType%22%3E%3C!%5BCDATA%5Bfalse%5D%5D%3E%3C%2Fparam%3E%0A%09%09%09%3Cparam%20name%3D%22filterID%22%3E%3C!%5BCDATA%5Bfalse%5D%5D%3E%3C%2Fparam%3E%0A%09%09%09%3Cparam%20name%3D%22gridType%22%3E%3C!%5BCDATA%5B2%5D%5D%3E%3C%2Fparam%3E%0A%09%09%09%3Cparam%20name%3D%22classID%22%3E%3C!%5BCDATA%5B0%5D%5D%3E%3C%2Fparam%3E%0A%09%09%09%3Cparam%20name%3D%22endDateTimestampOld%22%3E%3C!%5BCDATA%5B1667043595%5D%5D%3E%3C%2Fparam%3E%0A%09%09%09%3Cparam%20name%3D%22forcedTeacher%22%3E%3C!%5BCDATA%5B0%5D%5D%3E%3C%2Fparam%3E%0A%09%09%09%3Cparam%20name%3D%22forcedClass%22%3E%3C!%5BCDATA%5B0%5D%5D%3E%3C%2Fparam%3E%0A%09%09%09%3Cparam%20name%3D%22forcedClassroom%22%3E%3C!%5BCDATA%5B0%5D%5D%3E%3C%2Fparam%3E%0A%09%09%09%3Cparam%20name%3D%22assignmentTypeID%22%3E%3C!%5BCDATA%5B1%5D%5D%3E%3C%2Fparam%3E%0A%09%09%3C%2Fparams%3E%0A%09%3C%2Fcommand%3E%0A%3C%2Frequest%3E'
```

then I get the result I wanted.
but if I do this exact request in c#:

```
using RestSharp;
namespace HelloWorldApplication
{
    class HelloWorld
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var client = new RestClient("https://dbh.smartschool.be/index.php?module=Agenda&file=dispatcher");
            client.Timeout = -1;
            var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
            request.AddHeader("authority", "dbh.smartschool.be");
            request.AddHeader("accept", "*/*");
            request.AddHeader("accept-language", "nl-BE,nl-NL;q=0.9,nl;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.6");
            request.AddHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
            request.AddHeader("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8");
            request.AddHeader("cookie", "pid=77573bd5-8567-4bed-8f03-19211db08663; PHPSESSID=s0qf6btgu15su1gesrubrm01lveov6far58r58r2vabvfpo60e");
            request.AddHeader("origin", "https://dbh.smartschool.be");
            request.AddHeader("pragma", "no-cache");
            request.AddHeader("referer", "https://dbh.smartschool.be/");
            request.AddHeader("sec-ch-ua", "\"Chromium\";v=\"106\", \"Google Chrome\";v=\"106\", \"Not;A=Brand\";v=\"99\"");
            request.AddHeader("sec-ch-ua-mobile", "?0");
            request.AddHeader("sec-ch-ua-platform", "\"Windows\"");
            request.AddHeader("sec-fetch-dest", "empty");
            request.AddHeader("sec-fetch-mode", "cors");
            request.AddHeader("sec-fetch-site", "same-origin");
            client.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/106.0.0.0 Safari/537.36";
            request.AddHeader("x-requested-with", "XMLHttpRequest");
            var body = @"command=%3Crequest%3E%0A%09%3Ccommand%3E%0A%09%09%3Csubsystem%3Eagenda%3C%2Fsubsystem%3E%0A%09%09%3Caction%3Eget%20lessons%3C%2Faction%3E%0A%09%09%3Cparams%3E%0A%09%09%09%3Cparam%20name%3D%22startDateTimestamp%22%3E%3C!%5BCDATA%5B1666611595%5D%5D%3E%3C%2Fparam%3E%0A%09%09%09%3Cparam%20name%3D%22endDateTimestamp%22%3E%3C!%5BCDATA%5B1667043595%5D%5D%3E%3C%2Fparam%3E%0A%09%09%09%3Cparam%20name%3D%22filterType%22%3E%3C!%5BCDATA%5Bfalse%5D%5D%3E%3C%2Fparam%3E%0A%09%09%09%3Cparam%20name%3D%22filterID%22%3E%3C!%5BCDATA%5Bfalse%5D%5D%3E%3C%2Fparam%3E%0A%09%09%09%3Cparam%20name%3D%22gridType%22%3E%3C!%5BCDATA%5B2%5D%5D%3E%3C%2Fparam%3E%0A%09%09%09%3Cparam%20name%3D%22classID%22%3E%3C!%5BCDATA%5B0%5D%5D%3E%3C%2Fparam%3E%0A%09%09%09%3Cparam%20name%3D%22endDateTimestampOld%22%3E%3C!%5BCDATA%5B1667043595%5D%5D%3E%3C%2Fparam%3E%0A%09%09%09%3Cparam%20name%3D%22forcedTeacher%22%3E%3C!%5BCDATA%5B0%5D%5D%3E%3C%2Fparam%3E%0A%09%09%09%3Cparam%20name%3D%22forcedClass%22%3E%3C!%5BCDATA%5B0%5D%5D%3E%3C%2Fparam%3E%0A%09%09%09%3Cparam%20name%3D%22forcedClassroom%22%3E%3C!%5BCDATA%5B0%5D%5D%3E%3C%2Fparam%3E%0A%09%09%09%3Cparam%20name%3D%22assignmentTypeID%22%3E%3C!%5BCDATA%5B1%5D%5D%3E%3C%2Fparam%3E%0A%09%09%3C%2Fparams%3E%0A%09%3C%2Fcommand%3E%0A%3C%2Frequest%3E";
            request.AddParameter("application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8", body, ParameterType.RequestBody);
            
            IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
            Console.WriteLine(response.StatusCode);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

I don't get any results. this code is directly from postmen so I don't get why it isn't working
any thoughts?

Comment: I think you might have forgotten to include your C# code.

Comment: Can you try by changing this code "request.AddParameter("application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8", body, ParameterType.RequestBody);"

to this

"request.AddParameter("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", body, ParameterType.RequestBody);"